# WPF - Automatically sizing forms

Tags: wpf

I'm in the process of learning WPF and I have a problem with a groupbox (without a height and width specified) taking up more space on the form than it needs.

From researching a few other posts on here (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4521508/543538)) I know that controls like groupboxes will expand to fill their container.

Is there a way of specifying in WPF that you'd like the form to automatically size to fit all of its components based on a total of their individual sizes? It seems a bit odd that if I'm using DockPanels that size to fit their components that the main window needs to be told the correct height and width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [`SizeToContent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent.aspx) to `WidthAndHeight` on the window.

Comment: Thanks! I thought there had to be a simple way of doing it, I'm surprised I missed that when I was researching it.