# preventing WPF Grid from infinit growth

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

My question is similar to:
[Prevent WPF control from expanding beyond viewable area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521508/prevent-wpf-control-from-expanding-beyond-viewable-area)
with the difference that the accepted solution (specific to the issue with StackPanel) does not really help me much.

I have a Window that currently only contains the following Grid:

```
 <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="265"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="147*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="173*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <local:BatteryGraphicsView x:Name="batView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ClipToBounds="True" Width="265"/>
 </Grid>
```

I want now that if my GraphicsView extends over the width of its column, that the scrollbars are displayed and the control does not paint it self beyond the bounds of the column.

This happens as soon as I press the button.
The user control basically is a grid that contains WinFormsHosts, when pressing the button there are more columns created for the grid and so the grid grows
(Usercontrol grid xaml)

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ClipToBounds="True">
    <Grid x:Name="Maingrid" ClipToBounds="True">                
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="host1" />
        <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="host2" Grid.Row="2"/>
        </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

While the Scollviewer realises that it needs to display it self, the mainGrid anyway is displayed beyond the bounds of the column.
In multiple related posts I saw that you need to set the "ClipToBounds" property to true, but I set the property for every control and there is still no reaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your ScrollViewer inside your UserControl doesn't know what the GridColumn & and GridRow sizes are.

There are two things you can do.

1:  Specify a MAX Width for your Column & Max Height for you Row

2:  Instead of adding your scrollViewer in the UserControl, add it in your grid and give it a height and width.